# Run autocommand if full file name does not include pattern

Tags: vim

I have a function to run `flake8` every time I save a python file. However I don't want that function to run if the full file name (full path) includes `/.git/`. How can I achieve that? I tried the following without success:

```
au BufWritePost */[^git]/*.py call s:MyFlake8()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do an early check at top of `MyFlake8` and exit if conditions are not met.

```
function! MyFlake8()
  if expand("%:p") =~ "/\\.git/"
    return
  endif

  echo "FLAKE8!"
endfunction
au BufWritePost *.py call s:MyFlake8()
```

Answer (score 2):

Negative file globs are difficult to achieve, but you can avoid the problem with a positive glob that sets an "ignore this" marker, and another global command (in that order!) that checks for that marker:

```
au BufWritePost */.git/*.py let b:insideGit = 1
au BufWritePost *.py if ! exists('b:insideGit') | call s:MyFlake8() | endif
```